Soft question on career paths
We often have new users asking basically the same question: "How do I become Quant". These questions should be closed since they are not in the QA-format and outside of the scope of the faq. However adding one such question has advantages:

People will continue to ask them anyways, polluting the frontpage. With their question  answered, new users don't have to ask;
Increase of visitors through organic search. These visitors may not be professional quants yet but they probably do fit the profile.

I therefore propose to add it despite the concerns and tag it clearly.

I'm open to the idea in theory, skeptical of how it will work out in practice.  I'll wait to hear more opinions before deciding my vote.

How do I become a quant? is about as bad as How do I find a spouse?. One person's experience isn't really going to help other people beyond a few generic pointers. Besides, there's already a whole book about this very topic.

Basically, the site is designed for professionals. So, How do I become a Quant? is by definition off-topic. If we don't want to change that, the real question I believe is How could we market this site?
